# Removing some strings at the end of a field in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in my SQL Server table called `brn_description` with the data below:

```
Minneapolis c0 02/14/18
Sacramento c0 02/14/18
Vancouver c0 02/14/18
```

I will like to remove all these "c0 02/14/18". It is about 11 characters from the right.

How do I remove these please and just return

```
Minneapolis 
Sacramento 
Vancouver
```

Comment: "about 11 characters"  or *exactly* 11 characters?

Comment: You have suggestions. Notice that they are all built on assumptions. Your first goal is to analyze your existing values to determine if there is a reliable pattern - one that you wish to use as the basis for a solution. Phrases like "about 11 characters" suggest you are still trying to hack a way to your goal. What happens when the city name is composed of multiple words (Los Angeles)? Is " c0 " always present? 2 digit years - who has not learned the lessons of Y2K? Does every row have these 3 elements? What should happen if they do not? Think first. Document your assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:
Replace @str with your column name

`Declare @str Nvarchar(MAX) ='Minneapolis c0 02/14/18'
SELECT left(@str,len(@str)-11)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `REPLACE` if your string is fixed

```
Declare @str Nvarchar(MAX) ='Minneapolis c0 02/14/18'
SELECT REPLACE(@str, 'c0 02/14/18', '');
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=338d0cf42f48e0c139a5b70a35a2395d)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=16045f1021424ac326006a8cf37cc4eb

Comment: as long as the substring to remove from the end isnt also contained in the middle of the string. So in this case I imagine it would

Answer (score 0):

You might want:

```
update t
    set brn_description = left(brn_description, len(brn_description) - 11)
    where col like '% c0 [0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]';
```

This actually changes the value of the column, where this pattern appears.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there are trailing spaces or CRLFs etc, I would opt to find the **c0** rather than trimming the last 11 characters

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'Minneapolis c0 02/14/18'

Select left(@S,charindex(' c0 ',@S+' c0 ')-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE brn_description SET column = LEFT(column, LEN(column) - 12)`

OR in this case, you can probably use CHARINDEX since the space is pretty obvious

`UPDATE brn_description SET column = LEFT(column, CHARINDEX(' ', column) - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remove every thing after the second space from the right (you can't use the first from the left if you got e.g. "Los Angeles"). Locate the index of that space with `charindex()` on the `reverse()` of the string. Once you got it you can subtract it from the length of the string, which you get with `len()` and take that many characters from the left with `left()` (the length is the same whether reversed or not, that's why this works).

```
SELECT left(brn_description, len(brn_description) - charindex(' ', reverse(brn_description), charindex(' ', reverse(brn_description)) + 1))
       FROM (SELECT 'Minneapolis c0 02/14/18' brn_description
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Sacramento c0 02/14/18' brn_description
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Vancouver c0 02/14/18' brn_description
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Los Angeles c0 02/14/18' brn_description) x;
```